# Can't get uib accordion template-url to work

Tags: angularjs, templates, angular-ui-bootstrap, accordion

I'm attemting to use uib-accordion and I want to have a checkbox in the header. According to the documentation you have to use a custom template for the accordion-group for this to work (Why they chose to not support clickable controls in the header by default puzzles me..) Now I've used custom templates with an url-resolver together with the uib-datepicker directive before without a problem and I thought that the same technique would work with the accordion template-url but apparently it's a different kettle of fish altogether(?)

With the datepicker directive I was able to do this:

```
datepicker-popup-template-url="{{ ctrl.contentUrlResolver.resolve('templates/datepicker/popup.html') }}"
```

and everything just worked, but when I similarly try to this with the accordion template-url, like this:

```
<uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
<uib-accordion-group heading="Custom template" template-url="{{ ctrl.contentUrlResolver.resolve('templates/accordion/accordion-group.html') }}">

</uib-accordion-group>
```

I instead get an 404:

> [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: {{ ctrl.contentUrlResolver.resolve('templates/accordion/accordion-group.html') }} (HTTP status: 404 )

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong and why the datepicker directive template-url is working without a hitch when the accordion template-url is crashing.

/Regards Kristofer

Comment: resolve your template path in your controller and only then provide it (as a string) to `template-url`

Comment: Sorry for getting back so late but I've been busy. Thanks for your reply. In the end I went for a different solution and used the accordion-header together with some custom javascript, but I'm sure it would have worked with your solution as well.